# Android SQLite - selectionArgs other than Strings

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have a table containing a BLOB column (it's just 16 bytes). I want to run a query of the form `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE blobColumn = ?` and bind a byte array to that column. Ideally I would be able to say
`myDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE blobColumn = ?", myByteArray)`
or some variant thereof, but the rawQuery function only supports String arguments - although looking though the Android sources, it seems that the private methods do include `bindBlob(int, byte[])`.

I can, of course, just run the query `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE blobColumn = x'CAFE1234CAFE1234CAFE1234CAFE1234'`, but is there a way to do it that doesn't require converting the blob to a string?

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your argument to your ? query:

new String [] { String.valueOf(mByteArray) }

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can compare the contents of a Blob field without first converting it.  Could you create an additional column and load it with some type of key that could be unique and descriptive of it's associated Blob data?